# Difference of a date and int column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
raw_data = {'SeriesDate':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'Test':['1','2','3','4']}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['SeriesDate','Test'])
df['SeriesDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SeriesDate'])
```

I want to subtract the number field from the date field to arrive at a date, however when I do this:

```
df['TestDate'] = df['SeriesDate'] - pd.Series((dd) for dd in df['Test'])
```

I get the following TypeError:

```
TypeError: incompatible type [object] for a datetime/timedelta operation
```

Any idea how I can workaround this?

Comment: does the items in Test represent days or secs or years?

Comment: it represents days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_timedelta`:

```
df['TestDate'] = df['SeriesDate'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['Test'].astype(int), unit="d")

print(df)

    SeriesDate  Test    TestDate
0   2017-03-10  1       2017-03-09
1   2017-03-13  2       2017-03-11
2   2017-03-14  3       2017-03-11
3   2017-03-15  4       2017-03-11
```

Comment: Don't think it's working. This seems to be always taking out 1 day from the SeriesDate.